# Jquery change HTML of multiple elements if their html is above current number

Tags: jquery, html

Alright so i'm creating a quiz where I'm dynamicly adding content but also removing it when needed.

This is my HTML:

```
<div class="well">
        <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" name="quizName" class="form-control" placeholder="Quiz name" aria-describedby="basic-addon1">
        </div>
        <hr/>
        <button id="add-tab" type="button"> Add Question</button>
        <div id="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="#tabs-1" class="ActiveQuestion">1</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div id="tabs-1" class="questionsList">
                Question: <input type="text" placeholder="What's your question?" name="question[]"/><br/><br/>
                <input type="text" class="question" name="awnser[1][]" placeholder="1st awnser"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="correct_awnser[1][]" value="1"/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" class="question" name="awnser[1][]" placeholder="2nd awnser"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="correct_awnser[1][]" value="2"/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" class="question" name="awnser[1][]" placeholder="3rd awnser"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="correct_awnser[1][]" value="3"/>
                <br/>
                <br/>
                <input type="text" class="question" name="awnser[1][]" placeholder="4th awnser"/>
                <input type="checkbox" name="correct_awnser[1][]" value="4"/>
                <br/>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button value="Save quiz" type="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
```

This is my Jquery:

```
function checkNumbers(number){
    $( "#tabs li a" ).each(function() {
        var curreId = $(this).attr("id").split('id-');
        console.log(curreId[1]);
        if(curreId[1] > number){
            console.log(" TRUE");
            console.log("New number: "+(curreId[1] - 1));
            $("#tabs ul li ").html((curreId[1] - 1));

            $(this).filter(function() {
                return $(this).html() == (number);
            }).html(curreId[1] - 1);
        }
    });
}
```

I'm using Jquery tabs which contain the question number (1,2,3,4)

When you remove the 2nd question the list would be: 1 - 3 - 4, I want to change this to 1 - 2 - 3 again. How can I achieve this with Jquery?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Never mind I just found my own mistake.

I had to change:

```
    if(curreId[1] > number){
        console.log(" TRUE");
        console.log("New number: "+(curreId[1] - 1));
        $("#tabs ul li ").html((curreId[1] - 1));

        $(this).filter(function() {
            return $(this).html() == (number);
        }).html(curreId[1] - 1);
    }
```

to :

```
    if(curreId[1] > number){
        console.log(" TRUE");
        console.log("New number: "+(curreId[1] - 1));
        $(this).html((curreId[1] - 1));
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you can streamline things a bit. It isn't really necessary to pull a number out of the ID tag if you intend to renumber everything sequentially anyway. If I understand your intent, you can use the index function to give every link element a sequential number starting at 1.

```
$('#tabs li a').each(function(){
   $(this).html($(this).parent().index() + 1);    
});
```

The 'parent()' is necessary because the index will be calculated relative to the element's siblings. The 'a' elements don't have siblings since there's only one in each li, but the li elements are are siblings and hence good candidates for 'index()'.

Here's a very streamlined example CodePen for proof of concept.
http://codepen.io/dharshba/pen/QbgaZv?editors=101